# Convert output of template matching image into binary image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have used cv2.matchTemplate() to identify target objects in an image. Now I want to convert below image into binary image(black and white) in such a way that detected target object(white frames) should be in white color and rest of the objects in image should be in black color. [image]

This is how I want an output(Binary output illustrative). Wherever white frames (in input image) is there, image area should be white and rest are in black color.
[image]

Comment: and what is your question? how did you achieve those white frames? that's not the output of cv2.matchTemplate().... if you can draw white frames you should be able to draw fille white frames as well... that's all you need to create a binary image if you know how to create a black image as well... provide more information and ask a particular question if you want an answer. please read [ask]

Comment: @Piglet I have used sample image for illustration but actual image is very similar with the image attached above.

Comment: and what stops you from filling those white frames?

Comment: @Piglet Can you help me in writing code to fill those white frames with white color and rest of the object in black. I'm new to python.

Comment: why is it that we always have to google for you guys? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html come on! how did you draw the frames if you don't know how to draw in the first place? I am really sorry but you have to think if you want to program. if you are not willing or able to think then better stop right now